# Unable to solve RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I am facing this error "RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`" when trying to fine tune the model "deepset/bert-base-cased-squad2" using the transformers library from hugging face.
I have already tried the following:

1. Changing the vocab size to be equal to the vocab size of the
   tokenizer
2. Using smaller batch sizes (8,4, and even 1)
3. Updating both pytoch and transformers

This is my code

```
import logging
import os
import time
from transformers import  AutoTokenizer
import json
import pandas as pd
import data_preparation_roberta as data_preparation
import fine_tuning_roberta as fine_tuning
import evaluation_roberta as evaluation
import visualisation
import random


def get_experiment_timestamp():
    return time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

model_name =  "deepset/bert-base-cased-squad2"
data_file = "../data/task1_ExtractiveQA_v5.xlsx"
experiment_timestamp = get_experiment_timestamp()
output_dir = f"../checkpoints/model_checkpoints/{model_name}_{experiment_timestamp}/"

seed = int(random.random()*100)

dataset_dict, tokenized_dataset= data_preparation.prepare_data(data_file,seed)

train_batch_size = 1
eval_batch_size = 1 
num_epochs = 3
learning_rate = 2e-5
max_length = 100
log_history = fine_tuning.train_model(model_name,dataset_dict,tokenized_dataset,
                            train_batch_size, eval_batch_size,
                           num_epochs, learning_rate,  max_length ,output_dir)
```

And this is the train_model function:

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments, Trainer
from transformers import default_data_collator
from transformers import  AutoTokenizer, TrainingArguments
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, Trainer
import torch

def train_model(model_name_hf,dataset_dict,tokenized_dataset, train_batch_size, eval_batch_size, num_epochs, learning_rate, max_length,output_dir):


    #model_name = 
    model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name_hf, torch_dtype=torch.float16)
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_hf)
    #inputs    = tokenizer(dataset_dict, return_tensors="pt")
    #model.cuda()
    #inputs = {k: v.cuda() for k, v in inputs.items()}
    #outputs   = model(**inputs)
    #features  = outputs[0][:,0,:].detach().numpy().squeeze()

    #custom_vocab_size = 50000
    #config = model.config
    #config.vocab_size = tokenizer.vocab_size
    #model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name_hf, torch_dtype=torch.float16, config = config)
    #config.vocab_size = custom_vocab_size
    #nlp = pipeline('question-answering', model=model_name, tokenizer=model_name)
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        output_dir=output_dir,
        logging_dir='logging_dir',
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
        logging_strategy="epoch",
        learning_rate=  learning_rate,  #2e-5,
        per_device_train_batch_size=train_batch_size,
        per_device_eval_batch_size=eval_batch_size,
        num_train_epochs=num_epochs,
        weight_decay=0.01,
        push_to_hub=False,
        #fp16=True,
        #gradient_checkpointing=True,
        #metric_for_best_model = 'f1',
        #report_to="wandb",
        report_to=None
        )
    
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=tokenized_dataset["train"],
        eval_dataset=tokenized_dataset["valid"],
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        #data_collator=default_data_collator
    )

    #Fine tune the model.
    trainer.train()

    #Save the model to output dir.
    trainer.save_model(output_dir)

    #Save training and validation loss
    log_history= trainer.state.log_history
   
    return log_history
```

The error:

````
2023-09-04 09:26:47.427280: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Some weights of the model checkpoint at deepset/bert-base-cased-squad2 were not used when initializing BertForQuestionAnswering: ['bert.pooler.dense.bias', 'bert.pooler.dense.weight']        
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertForQuestionAnswering from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForQuestionAnswering from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
huggingface/tokenizers: The current process just got forked, after parallelism has already been used. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, you can either:
        - Avoid using `tokenizers` before the fork if possible
        - Explicitly set the environment variable TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
huggingface/tokenizers: The current process just got forked, after parallelism has already been used. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, you can either:
        - Avoid using `tokenizers` before the fork if possible
        - Explicitly set the environment variable TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
huggingface/tokenizers: The current process just got forked, after parallelism has already been used. Disabling parallelism to avoid deadlocks...
To disable this warning, you can either:
        - Avoid using `tokenizers` before the fork if possible
        - Explicitly set the environment variable TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=(true | false)
  0%|                                                                                                                                                                  | 0/456 [00:00<?, ?it/s]You're using a BertTokenizerFast tokenizer. Please note that with a fast tokenizer, using the `__call__` method is faster than using a method to encode the text followed by a call to the `pad` method to get a padded encoding.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1146: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [553,0,0], thread: [96,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1146: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [553,0,0], thread: 
../aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:1146: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [553,0,0], thread: [95,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ /root/Desktop/workspace/Evaluation-results/aut_train_eval/scripts/debug_ft.py:32 in <module>     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   29 num_epochs = 3                                                                              │
│   30 learning_rate = 2e-5                                                                        │
│   31 max_length = 100                                                                            │
│ ❱ 32 log_history = fine_tuning.train_model(model_name,dataset_dict,tokenized_dataset,            │
│   33 │   │   │   │   │   │   │   train_batch_size, eval_batch_size,                              │
│   34 │   │   │   │   │   │      num_epochs, learning_rate,  max_length ,output_dir)              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /workspace/Evaluation-results/aut_train_eval/scripts/fine_tuning_roberta.py:53 in train_model    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   50 │   )                                                                                       │
│   51 │                                                                                           │
│   52 │   #Fine tune the model.                                                                   │
│ ❱ 53 │   trainer.train()                                                                         │
│   54 │                                                                                           │
│   55 │   #Save the model to output dir.                                                          │
│   56 │   trainer.save_model(output_dir)                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1555 in train                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1552 │   │   │   finally:                                                                      │
│   1553 │   │   │   │   hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()                                       │
│   1554 │   │   else:                                                                             │
│ ❱ 1555 │   │   │   return inner_training_loop(                                                   │
│   1556 │   │   │   │   args=args,                                                                │
│   1557 │   │   │   │   resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,                            │
│   1558 │   │   │   │   trial=trial,                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:1837 in _inner_training_loop      │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1834 │   │   │   │   │   self.control = self.callback_handler.on_step_begin(args, self.state,  │
│   1835 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1836 │   │   │   │   with self.accelerator.accumulate(model):                                  │
│ ❱ 1837 │   │   │   │   │   tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)                      │
│   1838 │   │   │   │                                                                             │
│   1839 │   │   │   │   if (                                                                      │
│   1840 │   │   │   │   │   args.logging_nan_inf_filter                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2682 in training_step             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2679 │   │   │   return loss_mb.reduce_mean().detach().to(self.args.device)                    │
│   2680 │   │                                                                                     │
│   2681 │   │   with self.compute_loss_context_manager():                                         │
│ ❱ 2682 │   │   │   loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)                                       │
│   2683 │   │                                                                                     │
│   2684 │   │   if self.args.n_gpu > 1:                                                           │
│   2685 │   │   │   loss = loss.mean()  # mean() to average on multi-gpu parallel training        │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py:2707 in compute_loss              │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2704 │   │   │   labels = inputs.pop("labels")                                                 │
│   2705 │   │   else:                                                                             │
│   2706 │   │   │   labels = None                                                                 │
│ ❱ 2707 │   │   outputs = model(**inputs)                                                         │
│   2708 │   │   # Save past state if it exists                                                    │
│   2709 │   │   # TODO: this needs to be fixed and made cleaner later.                            │
│   2710 │   │   if self.args.past_index >= 0:                                                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py:1844 in forward │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1841 │   │   """                                                                               │
│   1842 │   │   return_dict = return_dict if return_dict is not None else self.config.use_return  │
│   1843 │   │                                                                                     │
│ ❱ 1844 │   │   outputs = self.bert(                                                              │
│   1845 │   │   │   input_ids,                                                                    │
│   1846 │   │   │   attention_mask=attention_mask,                                                │
│   1847 │   │   │   token_type_ids=token_type_ids,                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py:1022 in forward │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1019 │   │   │   inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,                                                  │
│   1020 │   │   │   past_key_values_length=past_key_values_length,                                │
│   1021 │   │   )                                                                                 │
│ ❱ 1022 │   │   encoder_outputs = self.encoder(                                                   │
│   1023 │   │   │   embedding_output,                                                             │
│   1024 │   │   │   attention_mask=extended_attention_mask,                                       │
│   1025 │   │   │   head_mask=head_mask,                                                          │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py:612 in forward  │
│                                                                                                  │
│    609 │   │   │   │   │   encoder_attention_mask,                                               │
│    610 │   │   │   │   )                                                                         │
│    611 │   │   │   else:                                                                         │
│ ❱  612 │   │   │   │   layer_outputs = layer_module(                                             │
│    613 │   │   │   │   │   hidden_states,                                                        │
│    614 │   │   │   │   │   attention_mask,                                                       │
│    615 │   │   │   │   │   layer_head_mask,                                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py:497 in forward  │
│                                                                                                  │
│    494 │   ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:                                                             │
│    495 │   │   # decoder uni-directional self-attention cached key/values tuple is at positions  │
│    496 │   │   self_attn_past_key_value = past_key_value[:2] if past_key_value is not None else  │
│ ❱  497 │   │   self_attention_outputs = self.attention(                                          │
│    498 │   │   │   hidden_states,                                                                │
│    499 │   │   │   attention_mask,                                                               │
│    500 │   │   │   head_mask,                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py:427 in forward  │
│                                                                                                  │
│    424 │   │   past_key_value: Optional[Tuple[Tuple[torch.FloatTensor]]] = None,                 │
│    425 │   │   output_attentions: Optional[bool] = False,                                        │
│    426 │   ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:                                                             │
│ ❱  427 │   │   self_outputs = self.self(                                                         │
│    428 │   │   │   hidden_states,                                                                │
│    429 │   │   │   attention_mask,                                                               │
│    430 │   │   │   head_mask,                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py:286 in forward  │
│                                                                                                  │
│    283 │   │   past_key_value: Optional[Tuple[Tuple[torch.FloatTensor]]] = None,                 │
│    284 │   │   output_attentions: Optional[bool] = False,                                        │
│    285 │   ) -> Tuple[torch.Tensor]:                                                             │
│ ❱  286 │   │   mixed_query_layer = self.query(hidden_states)                                     │
│    287 │   │                                                                                     │
│    288 │   │   # If this is instantiated as a cross-attention module, the keys                   │
│    289 │   │   # and values come from an encoder; the attention mask needs to be                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1501 in _call_impl             │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1498 │   │   if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks   │
│   1499 │   │   │   │   or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks                   │
│   1500 │   │   │   │   or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):                   │
│ ❱ 1501 │   │   │   return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)                                          │
│   1502 │   │   # Do not call functions when jit is used                                          │
│   1503 │   │   full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []                             │
│   1504 │   │   backward_pre_hooks = []                                                           │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py:114 in forward                 │
│                                                                                                  │
│   111 │   │   │   init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)                                        │
│   112 │                                                                                          │
│   113 │   def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:                                            │
│ ❱ 114 │   │   return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)                                     │
│   115 │                                                                                          │
│   116 │   def extra_repr(self) -> str:                                                           │
│   117 │   │   return 'in_features={}, out_features={}, bias={}'.format(                          │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`
  0%|                                                                                           ```

Any help is appreciated.


**EDIT**
I found out later on that I was not passing the correct Tokenizer to the Trainer. It caused the input to the embeddings layers to be in the wrong shape.
````